# images are not centralized in slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a newbie in design and have had some troubles with this project.

I'm using Easyslider for the banner, and the images are scrolling just fine. However, they are not centralized in Google Chrome, and not displaying in Firefox. Working fine on IE. And I cannot figure how to make the smaller images bellow the banner the navigation controllers. I know it's definitely a problem between the screen and the seat, but I've been stuck with this issue for a few days and don't seem to figure it out, getting desperate enough.

Here is the url:

http://palcco.com.br/ftp/kunzler/

The HTML bit:

```
    <section class="banner">
    <ul>                
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_central_02.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_central_03.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/banner_central_04.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>     
    </ul>
    </section>


    <section class="container">


     <section class="container">
     <section class="box">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">
     <img src="img2/banner_central_2_control.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     </section><!--box-->
     </section><!--container--> 

     <section class="container">
     <section class="box2">
     </a>
     </section><!--box2-->
     </section><!--container-->

     <section class="container">
     <section class="box3">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">
     <img src="img2/banner_central_4_control.png" alt="">
     </a>
     </section><!--box3-->
     </section><!--container-->
```

The jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

         $(document).ready(function(){  
        $  j(".banner").easySlider({
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            nextId: "slider1next",
            prevId: "slider1prev"
            });
              });   
       </script>
```

And the CSS:

```
    .banner{
        width:100%;
        height:25em !important;
    }

    .banner ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .banner li{
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .banner li img{
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .box{
        background-color:#000;
        width:19.62%;
        height:6.25em;
        float:left;
        border:solid 3px #FFF;
        position:absolute;
        top:430px;
        display:inline;
    }

    .box:hover{
        border:solid 3px #FAAF3A;
    }

    .box img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .box2{
        width:19.62%;
        height:6.25em;
        float:right;
        border:solid 3px #FFF;
        position:absolute;
        top:430px;
        margin-left:314px;
        display:inline;
    }

    .box2:hover{
        border:solid 3px #FAAF3A;
    }


    .box2 img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .box3{
        width:19.62%;
        height:6.25em;
        float:right;
        border:solid 3px #FFF;
        position:absolute;
        top:430px;
        margin-left:628px;
        display:inline;
    }

    .box3:hover{
        border:solid 3px #FAAF3A;
    }


    .box3 img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Apologies for the messy code and many thanks in advance.

Cris

Comment: Use `margin:auto;` to center content.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have margin auto on both left & right.

```
.banner li img{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the slow reply, I had sorted it differently! That works, but it cuts part of the images if I set a fix width for the banner. I have this issue if the width is set for 100%, so that it addapts to different screen resolutions.

Comment: You could try adding a min-width and keep width:100%;

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that I can see what you're experiencing.

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a fiddle, but none of the ppaths for the images worked. When I set a fix width for the banner images, they centralize, but do not resize for screens with smaller resolutions (their wisth is 1600px). Once I try all the fixes, such as min-width, text-align:center, max-width:100%, etc, they are not centralized, when they rotate they stop in the middle of the screen.